# Core Data: Is it possible to build a desktop app to create the data model for an iPhone app with Core Data?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data

I'm currently in the process of deciding whether or not to use Core Data for managing the data in my iphone application.

The application involves putting together a fairly sizeable library of content which needs to be localised and has a fair few relationships. One benefit I thought of using core data would be that I could perhaps build a desktop client for managing the data of the application, then package the resulting file with the iPhone app to use as its content database.

With my fairly limited knowledge of Core Data I wanted to know if this is possible? Are their any best-practices people can point me in the direction of?

Comment: Keep in mind that Core Data on the iPhone is still under NDA, so you shouldn't ask too-specific questions about it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically a dupe of this question:

[Provide Base Data for Core Data Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928177/provide-base-data-for-core-data-application/928390#928390)

Short answer is - YES. I've done it, Apple does it. Works well.

Answer (score 0):

Core Data defines the interface for interacting with the database, not the storage itself. You can use XML, Binary, or SQLite as the storage file. If you want a quick-and-dirty solution, you could use a basic SQLite application such as Menial's Bases to create a database. You can then add this to your XCode project for use by the iPhone. If you intend for the desktop client to be used by your iPhone customers, you can can use much of the same Core Data code from your iPhone project.

Answer (score -1):

Core Data is now included starting a SDK 3.0.