# Can I read AND write to a db in my main bundle using core data?

Tags: database, core-data, bundle

With the particular app I am working on, I have a significant amount of data that I need to have in my db so I can read it in. I also have the need to write a few things to the db. I took a copy of the sqlite db out of the documents folder and put it into my main bundle and can read my manually inserted data without problems.

I am now trying to insert data, but I am running into difficulty. I remember reading somewhere that you can't write to a db in the main bundle? Only the documents folder? Is that correct? What are my options if I need to have custom data in a core data db that I also need write to?

Should I move it out of the main into the documents folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't find documentation to back this up, but it is my understanding that the application bundle is read-only. I have read that if you have a pre-populated Core Data store in the app bundle, you need to copy it to the Documents directory - and then make modifications that copy.

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928177/provide-base-data-for-core-data-application).